# How to find the area inside the larger loop and outside the smaller loop of the limacon $r=\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

How to find the area inside the larger loop and outside the smaller loopof the limacon $r=\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta$?

Once the integrals are set up, I know how to solve them, but I'm having difficulty setting the integrals up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The area of one half of the outer loop is given by $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi/3} (\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta)^2 d\theta$. See [This.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20r%3D1%2F2%2Bcos(theta)%20from%200%20to%202pi%2F3)

The area of one half of the inside loop is given by $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{\pi}^{4\pi/3} (\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta)^2 d\theta$. See [This.](http://graph%20r=1/2+cos(theta)%20from%20pi%20to%204pi/3)

Now, we subtract the outer loop from the inner loop and multiply by $2$ to account for symmetry:

$$2\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi/3} (\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta)^2 d\theta-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{\pi}^{4\pi/3} (\frac{1}{2} +\cos \theta)^2 d\theta\right)$$

Comment: How do you know what the bounds of integration are?

Comment: I suggest graphing the function using a few points. As you practice, you'll get a better idea of what bounds to use